# Which states allow disclosing photos of one's own voting ballot to a vote-swap partner?

Tags: united-states, voting

This is a follow-up to [this answer by Dawn](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/13971/fences-around-the-laws-vote-swapping/13972#13972) who explained that anti-ballot-photos laws have been struck down in:

California: [AB-1494](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/billNavClient.xhtml?bill_id=201520160AB1494).

New Hampshire: [Rideout v. Gardner](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/billNavClient.xhtml?bill_id=201520160AB1494).

Indiana: [American Civil Liberties Union of Indiana v. Indiana Secretary of State](http://www.thedcregister.com/news-briefs/aclu-wins-challenge-state%E2%80%99s-ballot-photo-law).

On the other hand, posting completed ballots is [illegal in Wisconsin](http://host.madison.com/wsj/news/local/govt-and-politics/elections/don-t-post-photo-of-ballot-on-facebook-or-twitter/article_7ee3a3ea-a6a8-11e1-b4c6-0019bb2963f4.html).

When [vote-swapping](http://cdn.ca9.uscourts.gov/datastore/opinions/2007/08/06/0655517.pdf), without the ability to share photos of completed ballots it's not possible to check whether participants in a vote swap honor their agreements.

Which states allow disclosing photos of one's own voting ballot to a vote-swap partner?

Comment: I think this is mostly a good question, but the part about your motivation to vote-swap is a little distracting from the central issue of just getting a list of states that allow ballot photos. I'd suggest removing the last two paragraphs.

Comment: @Dawn: I've included the motivation because there could be some nuances in the laws that I'm not aware of. For example, suppose in a certain state it's illegal to share one's ballot publicly, but it's legal to show the ballot privately to one named person, such as the vote-swapping partner arranged by the vote-swapping site. Then the answer to the title question for that state would be "illegal", but for vote swapping purposes it would be "legal". One can think of many nuances and exclusions that may affect applicability of the answer; therefore it makes sense to be specific.

Comment: Okay, I edited the title to clarify you want that purpose taken into consideration. Hope that helps.